# OR in WHERE clause is slowing down sql query performance ( sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm seeing a performance issue in one of the sproc that we use in our application.

It’s a very big sproc and I have narrowed it down to the part where I'm seeing performance issue.

It’s in the where clause ( copied below). Query estimation plan shows this part takes about 80%.

Logic is that `@AssignedToIds` and `@AssignedToRoleIds` can be null, it is it null then we will pull all the records.
Temp tables can have multiple rows. Any help on improving the performance is greatly appreciated.

`#AssignedTo` and `#AssignedToRole` are temp tables.

`#AssignedTo` has only one value in the table and `#AssignedToRole` is empty

SQL:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2000 t.Member_Party_PartyId AS Member_Party_PartyId
FROM Task t
WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
    AND (
        t.DueDate >= @DueStart
        OR @DueStart IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        t.DueDate <= @DueEnd
        OR @DueEnd IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        (
            @FilterType = 'MyPatients'
            AND t.AssignedUserId = @UserId
            )
        OR @FilterType != 'MyPatients'
        )
    AND (@FilterType != 'MyRole')
    AND (
        (
            @FilterType = 'MyGroup'
            AND t.AssignedUserId IN (
                SELECT PartyId
                FROM #OrgMembers
                )
            )
        OR @FilterType != 'MyGroup'
        )
    AND (
        (
            @FilterType = 'Custom'
            AND vpad.Provider IN (
                SELECT PartyId
                FROM #OrgMembers
                )
            )
        OR @FilterType != 'Custom'
        )
    AND (
        (
            @ActiveCase = 1
            AND cases.CaseId IS NOT NULL
            )
        OR @ActiveCase = 0
        )
    AND (
        t.TaskStatusId IN (
            SELECT TaskStatusId
            FROM #TaskStatus
            )
        )
    AND (
        t.TaskCategoryId IN (
            SELECT TaskCategoryId
            FROM #TaskCategory
            )
        OR @TaskCategoryIds IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        t.TaskPriorityId IN (
            SELECT TaskPriorityId
            FROM #TaskPriority
            )
        OR @TaskPriorityIds IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        rm.RegistryId IN (
            SELECT RegistryId
            FROM #Registry
            )
        OR @RegistryIds IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        (
            fg.CareMeasureId IN (
                SELECT CareMeasureId
                FROM #CareMeasure
                )
            AND exclusion.MemberId IS NULL
            )
        OR @CareMeasureIds IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        vpad.OrganizationId IN (
            SELECT OrganizationId
            FROM #Organization
            )
        OR (
            SELECT count(OrganizationId)
            FROM #Organization
            ) = 0
        )
    AND (
        vpad.Provider IN (
            SELECT ProviderId
            FROM #Provider
            )
        OR @ProviderIds IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        cases.CaseTypeId IN (
            SELECT CaseTypeId
            FROM #CaseType
            )
        OR @CaseIds IS NULL
        )
    AND
    --(case when @AssignedToIds  Is Not Null And then t.AssignedUserId in (select AssignedToId from #AssignedTo))
    (
        (
            t.AssignedUserId IN (
                SELECT AssignedToId
                FROM #AssignedTo
                )
            OR (
                @AssignedToIds IS NULL
                AND @AssignedToRoleIds IS NULL
                )
            )
        OR (
            t.AssignedRoleId IN (
                SELECT AssignedRoleId
                FROM #AssignedToRole
                )
            OR (
                @AssignedToRoleIds IS NULL
                AND @AssignedToIds IS NULL
                )
            )
        )
    AND (
        vpad.OrganizationId IN (
            SELECT OrganizationId
            FROM #UserOrgs
            )
        OR (
            (
                SELECT count(OrganizationId)
                FROM #UserOrgs
                ) = 0
            )
        OR (@RoleType <> 'Manager')
        )
    AND (
        (
            mhp.MemberHealthPlanTypeId IN (
                SELECT HealthPlanId
                FROM #HealthPlan
                )
            AND hpds.HierarchyOrder IS NOT NULL
            )
        OR @HealthPlanIds IS NULL
        )
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: why the subselects? why not just join against them?

Comment: Join won't work. These are conditional joins. I only need to join temp tables if variables --@--AssignedToIds or --@--AssignedToRoleIds has values.

Comment: You have top x rows but no order by. With no order by you have no way of knowing which rows will be returned.

Comment: It seems like there's gotta be a cleaner way of writing this.  Normally I don't recommend dynamic SQL, but in this case maybe worth looking into?

Comment: Thanks. I'm going give a try if I don't get any other ideas from the forum.

Comment: Seriously consider if you can rewrite various `IN`s as left joins. Since you have taken the trouble of already populating those temp tables. Do they have many records? Would it be practical to simply pre-populate them with _everything_ if the parameter indicates?It's certainly worth a try. Also `DISTINCT` smells. If you have duplicates, work out which join is producing them and fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

You Could try adding

```
option(recompile)
```

To the end of that SQL query. See if that speeds it up a bit.

Comment: I think we may need to see the entire query here. It is perhaps possible you might have to do that check with the help of a temp table with an index to speed it up or something. It is hard to make that assumption with just that one where statement though.

Comment: Thanks for looking. Here is the full query

Answer (score 0):

Personally with so many conditions in this where clause it is going to be a nightmare to figure out where the performance issue is.

If it was me I would look to split this query down into smaller queries so that you are working on ever decreasing sub sets.

eg get the results of just

```
INSERT INTO myWorkingTable (some columns here....)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT TOP 2000 
    t.Member_Party_PartyId AS Member_Party_PartyId
FROM  
    Task t 
WHERE 
    t.IsDeleted = 0
```

then from these results work through the next set of queries and where possible include any of your conditional logic.

eg. 
so for example your logic for:

```
(
t.DueDate >= @DueStart 
OR 
    @DueStart IS NULL
)
```

could be

```
IF(@DueStart IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
 --LEAVE ONLY THOSE ITEMS WHERE @DueStart >= dueDate
 DELETE FROM myWorkingTable WHERE t.DueDate < @DueStart 
END
```

So other conditions like this can be performed outside of the "main" query.

Then you can eventually run a execution plan to check against the complete query and then apply any suggested indexes that the plan suggests.

I know it doesn't directly answer the question but with something this monolithic it is going to be pretty much impossible for someone to just say "your problem is with this bit"

Although doing NULL Checks within a where clause can be costly.